# Add animation to uiview moving from point A to point B

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a gesture which action moves a UIView to point B from point A. How can I add a nice transition of the UIView moving from point A to point B. I am looking at making it slowly move from point A to point B. How would I do this? At the moment to move the item I set the frame to point B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this code and set frame what you want

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 70, 100, 100);
}];
```

Comment: What do I define _animation1 and _animationInProgress as?

Comment: if you want to do something on completion of animation you can do that there just remove _animationInProgress

Comment: I get undefined identifier for _animation1 do I just remove that if I just want the animation but nothing to happen afterwards?

Comment: do you want second view to be removed after first view reach there?

Comment: It is just the one view. I want to move the uiview to point B. Also what headers do I need to include as I also get this error:  no known class method for selector
      'animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:animations:completion:

Comment: this is very simple check code now and adjust animation time whatever you want

Comment: I get the compile error: no known class method for selector 'animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:animations:completion is there a header I need to include?

Comment: use this code [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 70, 100, 100);
}];

Answer (score 2):

If you're using auto-layout (and you almost certainly are - it's the default) then @PinkeshGjr s solution is likely to have problems. With AutoLayout you can't manipulate a view's frame directly. At some point after moving the frame the view's constraints can snatch it back.

Instead, you want to create constraints that control the property/properties that you want to animate (x and y position in this case) and control-drag from the constraints into your view controller's header to create outlets.

Then you want to change the constant value on the constraints and call `layoutIfNeeded` inside your animation code. Something like this:

```
buttonXConstraint.constant = 100;
buttonYConstraint.constant = 100;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
  [self.button layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

The code above assumes that you've created 2 constraint outlets and called them `buttonXConstraint` and `buttonYConstraint`.

Comment: This should be the correct answer hands down. Come on, we are in 2016, everyone MUST use constraints. I'd be really happy if Apple removed frame  layout support completely from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using `animateKeyframesWithDuration` or `animateWithDuration:animations` but it will be just a linear interpolation. If you want to have more control over the animation I recommend that you take a look at [MTAnimation](https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTAnimation) it's really a powerful and easy to use Lib for achieving beautiful animations

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Very nice helper method to use for animating view.

```
- (void) animateView:(UIView *)view ToFrame:(CGRect) frame withDuration:(float) duration withDelay:(float) startDelay
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:startDelay options:0 animations:^{

        view.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        // Completion actions
    }];
}
```